# WPF Tabcontrol. Bind button to a command with CanExecute conditions are in childview

Tags: c#, wpf, button, command, tabcontrol

This is the scenario: In a UserControl there is TabControl, which loads different views, and a button. Like this image:

[Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCunk.png)

Button "Save" only can be enabled if fields "Name" and "Owner" are not empty. **These fields are in a child view loaded in ItemTab.**

This is the XAML (only with 1 TabItem to simplify)

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="Winvet.Desktop.Views.VCliente.DatosCliente"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Winvet.Desktop.ViewModels.VMCliente"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Winvet.Desktop.Views.VCliente">

    <Grid Margin="10 5 10 10">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TabControl Grid.Column="0" Name="TabDatosCliente" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsTabDatosCliente}" SelectedIndex="0">

            <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:DatosClienteGeneralViewModel}">
                    <views:DatosClienteGeneral/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.Resources>

            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>  

        </TabControl>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Command="{ I want to bind this }">Guardar</Button>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And this is the ViewModel (only 1 TabItem to simplify)

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Winvet.Desktop.Common;

namespace Winvet.Desktop.ViewModels.VMCliente
{
    public class DatosClienteViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {                 
        public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> ItemsTabDatosCliente { get; private set; }
        public DatosClienteViewModel()
        {
            ItemsTabDatosCliente = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>
            {
                new DatosClienteGeneralViewModel()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I wan't to create a Command which checks if those two child view fields are not empty and enables button. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routed commands burrow and bubble through the entire interface, so as long as you are in the same visual branch as the item raising the event, then you can handle it anywhere.

so in your VIEW

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(command, execute, canExecute));
    }

    private void canExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        //at this point you can pass it to your ViewModel
    }

    private void execute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        //at this point you can pass it to your ViewModel
    }
}
```

where command is the RoutedCommand that is set on your buttons Command Property